# Header overlaps content DIV in jquery-mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js

i thought this would be a problem of jquery-mobile 1.1.0 RC.
But also in the final release i got this weird problem, that my header overlaps my content div:

[image: Header including navbar overlaps my content div]

When i now click somewhere in the content div, the page rerenders and the content div is at the correct position(directly beneath the header).

I'm using Backbone.js Views for representing content, and jquery-mobile-router. I tried almost everything but i counldn't find any solution for this problem.

Does anyone know a solution for that?

html:

```
<!-- newsoffers page -->
<div data-role="page" id="newsoffers">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" data-fullscreen="false" data-position="fixed">
    </div>
    <!-- /content -->
    <div data-role="content" data-scroll="true" class="content-full">
    </div>
    <!-- /content -->
    <div id="newsoffersFooter" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-fullscreen="false" data-id="mainFooter" data-theme="b">
    </div>
    <!-- /footer -->
</div>
```

the code for the header is dynamically injected! The content will be injected while the "pagebeforeshow" event is fired.

[image: code for showing page]

"setNavBarCollection" adds a backbone collection to the header, which is then rendered as a navbar.
The "refreshOffers" function generates a view containing a backbone collection which is fetched asynchronously.

Comment: Are you using data-fullscreen=true on your page?

Comment: no, i'm not using it. it is set to false for every header

Comment: i added the html skeleton page

Comment: It seems to be connected to the following issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966869/image-in-jquery-mobile-fixed-header-overlaps-content-until-resize-event