# Image in jquery mobile fixed header overlaps content until resize event

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have an image in my jquery mobile fixed header.  When the page loads in Google Chrome or Apple Safari the header content overlaps the content div below the header until I resize the page.  Firefox and IE work just fine.

Thanks!

Comment: exactly what i am facing! troubleshooting... will share solution, if i can find out.

Comment: @kctang Have you tried specifying the height of the image?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think the problem is that when jQuery Mobile initializes the page, the header image is not loaded and the header is much smaller so jQuery Mobile puts a padding on the `.ui-page` element that is too small once the image loads. A simple fix for this is to manually set the size of the header image so that it takes-up it's required space even before its source loads.

You could also do this, although it seems pretty hacky to me, force a redraw by triggering the `resize` event on `document.ready` or maybe `window.load`:

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
    $(this).trigger('resize');
});
```

I pasted this code into the console while on your page and it re-positioned the title element as expected.

Comment: Ummm... well this is embarrassing.  Once I plugged in the image height and width attributes it worked perfectly.  Unbelievably simple.  Thank you.

Comment: **solution from *Carlos*** below seems **more appropriate**: **do it with the jQM loading functionality: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20554633/1915920**
and issue is known already since 2012: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5532, https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4562

Comment: @AndreasDietrich Kind of an interesting situation. If you trigger the `resize` event on `pageshow`, it's not a sure thing that the image has loaded and therefore has dimensions. However if you trigger the `resize` event on `load` then you won't get the benefit for subsequent page-loads via AJAX. I still suggest setting the size of the image in CSS or as an attribute on the image element.

Comment: @Jasper: yeah right ... added the *image dimension situation* to my more complete answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27828642/1915920

Answer (score 3):

Does applying the following CSS help?

```
.ui-page {
    padding-top: 91px !important;
}
```

*Note that you will have to refine the selector as this will apply to overlay popups either.*

Comment: I'm having the same type of problem, but my header has no image in it.  Regardless, this solution fixed my problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had lots of trouble with this. This worked until I wanted to add a link:

```
<div data-role="header">
  <img border="0" src="logo.png" style="float:left;display:inline"/> <h1></h1>
</div>
```

Note the empty h1 tag.

I ended up not using a data-role="header" at all, I just couldn't get it to work with a link. I used a ui-bar class instead. Like this:

```
<div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a">
    <a href="/" data-role="none">
        <img border="0" src="images/logo.png" style="float: left; display:inline">
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution based on @Jasper answer that worked for me was:

```
$(document).on('pageshow', "div[data-role='page']", function () {
    $(window).trigger('resize');
});
```

It has an improvement that apply to all the **jquery mobile pages**

Comment: great thx and: **instead of `pageshow` one should use `pagecontainershow` since 1.4.0!**

Comment: but it **only worked for me doing it a little bit later via `$(document).on( ... function() { setTimeout( function() { $(window).trigger('resize'); }, 100 /*ms*/ ); });`!** you may want to play with the `100` ms for your page. the solution from *Jasper* with `$(window).on('load', function() ... ` worked without the timeout, but may not be correct for every page navigation scenario

Answer (score 1):

I played with the rather good solutions from *Jasper* and *Carlos487* and **found this to be the most up-to-date and reliable way to do it (jQM 1.4.x)**:

1. **if** it's **due to an image without specified dimensions** that will need some time to load and thus may cause the header to enlarge, then **specifying the known dimensions (ideally via CSS) should do it**. Otherwise there should be a way to determine if it has finished loading and thus applying the idea of solution 3 below.
2. **if** it's is due to some (maybe) **unknown header resize event** (e.g. through some image loaded later or some other content shrinking the header and thus making it vertically bigger), then this should work with a reasonable **big enough timeout value**:

   ```
   $( ':mobile-pagecontainer' ).on( 'pagecontainershow', function(e) {
     // maybe value > 100 needed for your scenario / page load speed
     setTimeout( function() { $(window).trigger('resize'); }, 100 /*ms*/ );
   }
   ```
3. **if you know what is causing this** *(as in my case, where I am right shifting the page content on large screens via some (otherwise hidden/overlayed) left aligned navigation panel)*, then the following may be even better, **beeing independent of the actual time the page needs to load** on some device or scenario (which may be longer than your predefined timeout above):

   ```
   // if its due to some animation like in my case
   // otherwise try to find a similar way to determine when the resizing event has 
   // completed!
   $('#someAnimated').animate( 'complete', function() { $(window).trigger('resize'); });
   ```

(I am not sure if *Jasper*s solution using `$(window).on( 'load', ...` will be correct in all jQM page load scenarios (with AJAX page navigation). That's why I would prefer *Carlos487*'s approach in my example.)

Comment: Rather than relying on a hard-coded timeout while waiting for an image to load, you may just want to detect if there is an image in the header and attach an event handler to a `load` event for that image.

Comment: @Jasper: feel free to add such an example to scenario 3. in my post if you like

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions above worked for me. But I found out my problem lies in the events after the page navigation. If the content div is hidden during this time, it doesn't get positioned under the header div, rather stays in its original place:

```
$(document).on("pageshow", "div[data-role='page']", function()
{
   $("#pageContentDiv").hide();
   setTimeout(function()
   {
      $("#pageContentDiv").show();
   }, 0);
});
```

**EDIT:**
Found a better solution; set header div height and page div top padding to the same value:

```
<div data-role="page" style="padding-top: 60px">
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" style="height: 60px">
```

Hope this helps.