# Image in Jquery Mobile Header overlaps main content

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm developing a Cordova project, building the user interface with jQuery Mobile (first project using any of them), and I'm having problems adding a logo image to the header.

Since it makes the header bigger than default, the header overlaps the content in the main div as in this capture:

[image]

If I navigate to other page and return to this one, then everything looks like it should:

[image]

I've read that [when jQuery Mobile initializes the page, the header image is not loaded and the header is much smaller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11110607/3708095), so I've tried

this is my html for the image:

```
<div data-role="header" data-id="header" data-position="fixed">
  <h1>
    <img src="img/flycosette_logo-88cb7efa9f6acfcaf246f8523e87805d.png" alt="FlyCosette"/>
  </h1>
</div><!-- /header -->
```

And this my css in a custom file called after jQM files:

```
.ui-header img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

I've tried the approach in the quoted link:

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
  $(this).trigger('resize');
});
```

but it doesn't work for me.

I've also tried placing the image inside a `div`, instead `<h1>`, and setting the code for it instead of the image, playing with several properties, but it doesn't solve the problem and the image size does not display as well as in the screencaptures...

So, any idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After refactoring my code, I've been trying all different solutions once again, and it turns out that the initial solution:

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
  $(this).trigger('resize');
});
```

from the post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11110607/3708095
is what finally solved my problem.

I'm calling the script with that code after the `</body>` tag, below all the html (not sure about how was it being called before), and now is working.

Sorry for the inconveniences.

Answer (score 0):

When you get back to the page, JQM internally triggers an event called `upateLayout` which probably also adapts the content positioning relative to the header. Try triggering this yourself by doing something like:

```
 $([your_page]).trigger("updatLayout");
```

See if this works. Maybe you need to call it on the header or content instead of the page.

Comment: I've tried `$("#products > .ui-content").trigger("updateLayout");` being #products the id of the page that needs to be updated.
I've also tried with the header doing: `$("#products > [data-role='header']").trigger("updateLayout");`
No luck in either cases. Also with `$(document)...`

Comment: By the way, in my desktop using Chrome it's rendered Ok

Comment: so which browser is this?

Comment: It's a cordova application, and it's happening either in iOS or Android